# How to use OneDrive API to upload to shared folder?

Tags: onedrive

A client shared with me a folder on their OneDrive and they want me to upload files once a day. I registered an azure app as onedrive docs say but what I don't understand is where to go from there?
According to the docs I need to add a redirect url to use auth endpoint, but I want to make a background app without user interactions, and obtain a token automatically, and also the folder was shared with my work email, I don't have any microsoft users on that email and I don't have a password for it, will I be able to use the api with it?
And then for file upload docs give this kind of link

> /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

but where to get those drive-id and parent-id? all I have is a URL to the shared folder